# Recursion final number

Tags: c++

If my input number is 2...I understand that the function will take the previous answer and multiply by 2 until the number will be greater than 25

2 * 2 = 4

4 * 2 = 8

8 * 2 = 16

16 * 2 = 32...program stops since num is 32

but then my final number is 62 how am I getting that number>

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myRecursiveFunction (int num)
{
    if (num >= 25)           // stopping condition
        return num;
    else
        cout << "number is at " << num << endl;
        return num = num + myRecursiveFunction (num * 2);
}
int main()
{
    int num, num1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;
    num1 = myRecursiveFunction(num);
    cout << "Final number is: " << num1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 62` ... that's what you get! what is your expected result?

Comment: `return num = num + myRecursiveFunction (num * 2);` should be `num = num + myRecursiveFunction (num * 2); return num`

Comment: @Jessica `myRecursiveFunction (16 * 2)` returns `32` and you sum it up to `num`

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

2 * 2 = 4

4 * 2 = 8

8 * 2 = 16

16 * 2 = 32...program stops since num is 32

you are doing 
return num = num + myRecursiveFunction (num * 2);
which returns 32+16+8+4+2 = 62

Comment: So true
return num = num + myRecursiveFunction (num * 2); 
should be 
return num = myRecursiveFunction (num * 2);

Answer (score 0):

2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 62.
The return values are getting added each time.

Comment: well i figured it out (2+4+8+16+32) but why is 32 included? i thought it would stop at 16 since num is greater than 25

Comment: ahh yes 16 is the num 32 is the answer...so the num is not > 25

Comment: Because you call it with 16 * 2 so that it is 32, which is when it starts returning.

Comment: `num` is the parameter. If it is 16, it is less than 25, so the function returns `16 + recursiveFunction(2*16);`. When 2*16 (32) is the parameter, that is more than 25, so it returns 32.